# SQL results in single row

Tags: sql, database, oracle10g

Below is my table script and records.

```
create table prods
(prod_no varchar2(12));

insert into prods
values('MOBILE');

insert into prods
values('LAPTOP');
```

`select prod_no from prods;` gives me

```
MOBILE
LAPTOP.
```

How can I get the results like the following?

`MOBILE LAPTOP`. I would like the two records in one single row.

Comment: did you google it? - http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_sql_output_one_line.htm

Comment: Is there an additional requirement? There are several ways to do this. [Here's one](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/24337/6). Each solution may or may not work because as stated it not clear why you want to do this.

Comment: I would want this to do some checking. My table will always have two records, but data keeps changing.

Comment: @ConradFrix How can I eliminate the `with t as` from the sql and run? I would like to have the query with my real table and use the code in my procedure. Thanks

Comment: @Polappan I think you've misunderstood what the WITH block does. You don't need to nor should you want to eliminate it. The query I wrote does indeed select from the real table prods.

Comment: @ConradFrix Yes you are right it is from real tables. I was trying to do without `with` block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create table prods
(prod_no varchar2(12));

insert into prods
values('MOBILE');

insert into prods
values('LAPTOP');

select 
   rtrim (xmlagg (xmlelement (e, prod_no || ' ')).extract ('//text()'), ' ') list
from 
prods;

LIST                                                                            
---------------------------------------------------------
MOBILE LAPTOP                                                                   
1 row selected.
```

SQLFIDDLE:[link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/24337/7)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pivot the table. Go through the below URL

Visit: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/03/03/pivot-tables-in-sql-server-a-simple-sample.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
--Transact-SQL
--In this case, store in the variable varchar values
declare @result varchar(max) = '';

select @result = @result + prod_no + ' ' from prods;

select @result;
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not see the tag (sorry my english)